# AutoFill resets checkboxes

Tags: google-chrome, forms

I created a basic html forms which includes some selectable options via checkboxes and some textfields for things like user name and address data.
Each time a user tries to fill out the form with Chrome's AutoFill option, Chrome seems to uncheck all Checkboxes.
Is this a general Bug in Chrome and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have not seen this happen. However you could put off autocomplete=off in the FORM tag

Comment: i can reproduce it with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ttDMq/) basic form

Comment: I saw your code and it worked just fine, autofill did not uncheck the box for me. I'm using Chrome 27

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with Chromium, hopefully it will be fixed in the next version: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244645

Comment: A workaround is specified i the above link. Add autocomplete='off' to the input/checkbox field. Worked for me :-)